# R optimize script with a lot of loops

Tags: r

I have a list with hundreds of columns and rows.  What I'm doing is looping through nearly every possible iteration of taking the difference between two columns.  For example take the difference between 1st and 2nd column, 1st and 3rd column..1st and 500th column... 499th column and 500th column.  Once I have those differences I compute some descriptive statistics (ie. mean, st dev, kurtosis, skewness, etc) for output.  I know I can use lapply to calculate those statistics for each column individually but sd(x)-sd(y) <> sd(x-y) so it doesn't really cut down much on my looping.  I can use avg(x)-avg(y)=avg(x-y) but that's the only statistic where I can use this property.

Here's some pseudo code that I have:

```
    for (n1 in 1:(number of columns) {
        for (n2 in n1:(number of columns) {
            temp<-bigdata[n1]-bigdata[n2]
                 results[abc]<-(maxdrawdown,mean,skewness,kurtosis,count,st dev,
                       median, downsidedeviation)
         }
         }
```

Doing it this way can take literally days so I'm looking for some improvements.  I'm already using **Compiler** with `enableJIT(3)` which actually does make it noticeably faster.  I had a couple other ideas and any incites would be helpful.  One is trying to utilize the snowfall package (still trying to get my head around how to implement it) with the thought that one core could compute skew and kurtosis while the other computes the other statistics.  The other idea is creating big chunks of temp (ie. 1-2, 1-3, 1-4) as another data.frame (or list) so as to use lapply against it to knock out many iterations at once.  Would this make much of a difference?  Is there anything else I can do that I'm not even thinking of?

Comment: The `*apply` functions should be (much) faster, although I've got no figures to hand, and they're easy to use

Comment: @ChrisW: I think you will find that *apply are no faster than loops. They are certainly more compact and expressive, but benchmarking they will generally have the same performance. It's the interior functions that generally are the bottleneck.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example, especially because the words you use to describe your problem are very confusing.  Lists don't have rows/columns, they just have elements.  My guess is that `bigdata` is a data.frame, in which case converting `bigdata` to a matrix will be appreciably faster.

Comment: @DWin, hmm, you might be correct, although the answers http://www.quora.com/R-software/How-much-can-loops-slow-down-a-program-in-R-and-what-are-some-good-ways-to-avoid-them seem to suggest otherwise.  I guess it's dependent on so many factors tho

Comment: @ChrisW The very first example in that Quora thread is so blatantly wrong it hurts my head. Do not trust it. DWin is correct.

Comment: No, it's not 'dependent on a lot of factors'. It is dependent on the functions inside the loop and the appropriate use of vectorized functions when possible.  And don't believe everything you read on the internet. The "loop slower than apply" myth is widely promulgated, but it's still wrong.

Comment: I don't believe *anything* I read, hence questioning your comment ;) thanks though, I have been a victim of the 'apply is faster than loop' and had never really disbelieved it

Comment: @joran, I went back and accepted/voted for answers.

Comment: @joshua, with respect to the datatype I actually just found that I've been using mode instead of class which is why I described it as a list.  I'll try converting my data.frame to a matrix though and see how that does.

Comment: @ChrisW: The biggest problem with that first example is that `apply` converts `X` to a matrix, so they're really comparing matrix subsetting (which is fast) to data.frame subsetting (which is slow)... but attributing the speed difference to the loop.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich thanks - that makes some sense

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that not only was bigdata a data.frame but so is final.  First I changed bigdata to a matrix and that did not materially change how long it took.  Using a small subset the length of time went from about 1 minute 53 seconds to 1 minute 48 seconds.  I changed final from dataframe to matrix and now it takes 20 seconds.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich could you make your comment about converting from data frame to matrix an answer as that was the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible example would really help, because the way you describe your problem are confusing (e.g. lists don't have rows/columns). My guess is that `bigdata` and `results` are data.frames, in which case converting each of them to a matrix will make your loops appreciably faster.

Comment: your assumption about `bigdata` and `results` were correct and converting them to a matrix made them roughly 6 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be any faster, but the following might make the code a bit easier to read if not faster, although it should get a bit faster as well because you've eliminated the `for() ...`.

Try using `expand.grid()`, which I tend to use less often than I probably should

For instance:

```
nC <- 3 # Num of cols
nR <- 4 # Num of cols
indices <- expand.grid(nC, nC)
# Now you can use apply cleanly
apply(indices, 1,
   function(x) {
      c1 <- x[1]; c2 <- x[2]
      yourResult[c1,c2] <- doYourThing(bigData[,c1], bigData[,c2])
   }
)
```

Well, you get the idea. :-)